# Замена слова в подстроке пропустив n совпадающих с ним слов

Tags: php, строки

Доброго времени! Задача такая - есть строка

```
$str = "Шла саша по шосе и саша сосала сушку которую дала ей тетя саша";
```

В строке есть 3 слова "саша" стока может быть другая и тоже содержать N одинаковых слов - как сделать так что бы можно было заменить конкретное по счету слово "саша"? Можно наворочать цикел перебора из strpos но может есть более правильный способ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так

```
$str = "Шла саша по шосе и саша сосала сушку которую дала ей тетя саша";

function replaceNWord($string, $word, $to, $n = 1) {
    $tmp = explode(" ", $string);

    for ($i = 0, $j = 0; $i < count($tmp); $i++) {
        if ($tmp[$i] == $word) {
            if (++$j == $n) {
                $tmp[$i] = $to;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return implode(" ", $tmp);
}

echo replaceNWord($str, "саша", "Маша", 2);
```

Функция `replaceNWord()` возвращает измененную строку, если нашла совпадение и  принимает 4 параметра:

- `string` - изначальная строка
- `word` - слово, которое необходимо заменить
- `to` - слово, на которое необходимо заменить
- `n` - какое по счету повторение необходимо заменить

Результат

> Шла саша по шосе и Маша сосала сушку которую дала ей тетя саша

Answer (score 3):

Для слов состоящих из букв решение в одну строку:

```
$str = "Шла саша по шосе и саша сосала сушку которую дала ей тетя саша";

$num = 2;
$word = 'саша';
$repl = 'МАША';

$str = preg_replace('%^(.*?\b'.$word.'\b){'.($num-1).'}.*?\K\b'.$word.'\b%u', $repl, $str);

var_dump($str);
```

Результат:

```
string(112) "Шла саша по шосе и МАША сосала сушку которую дала ей тетя саша"
```

Если нужно считать слова без учета регистра, то добавите модификатор `i` в регулярку.

Если слово содержит спецсимволы, то обрабатывайте его функцией `preg_quote()`.

Подробно о регулярных выражениях в php [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = "Шла саша по шосе и саша сосала сушку которую дала ей тетя саша";

class ReplaceCallback
{
    private $counter = 0;
    private $replaceNumber;
    private $newWord;

    public function __construct($newWord, $replaceNumber = 1)
    {
        $this->newWord = $newWord;
        $this->replaceNumber = $replaceNumber;
    }

    public function callback($matches)
    {
        $this->counter++;
        if ($this->counter == $this->replaceNumber) {
            return $this->newWord;
        }

        return end($matches);
    }
}

$callback = new ReplaceCallback('Маша', 3);
echo preg_replace_callback("/(саша)/", array($callback, 'callback'), $str);
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Результат:
Шла саша по шосе и саша сосала сушку которую дала ей тетя Маша